# ui-router stateChangeStart per state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there any way to specify a `$stateChangeStart` *per* state?

For example, I can use this *global* `$stateChangeStart` event to capture state changes and reject particular ones:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (!user.isAdmin && toState.name === 'control-panel') {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
);
```

Since I need to set up permissions for many states, I'd prefer to do something like this instead:

```
$stateProvider.state('control-panel', {
    url: '/control-panel',
    template: '<control-panel></control-panel>',
    stateChangeStart: 
        function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (!user.isAdmin) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
});
```

What I'm trying to demonstrate in the second snippet is that I'm defining the `$stateChangeStart` even *only for one particular state*.

Is there a way to do that?

**EDIT: Solution I implemented goes something like this...**

```
$stateProvider.state('control-panel', {
    url: '/control-panel',
    template: '<control-panel></control-panel>',
    authorizeRoles: ['Admin']
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) { 
        if (toState.authorizeRoles && toState.authorizeRoles.length &&
            !_.intersection(toState.authorizeRoles, user.roles).length) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: You can also look forward for defining route patterns. Like for admin, you can have routes like `admin/...` ,

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that in the first snippet, I could check the route to see if it contains something like `admin/...` instead of checking the `toState.name`? I think that's one way to do it, but are routes are not structured around roles, unfortunately.

Comment: UI-Router doesn't do what you want. However, you can add a `data` property to each state which you could then inspect using a global state change handler. It's perhaps not as elegant as what you're proposing, but I've seen many people do that for simple "is login required" checks.